# How to change the limits of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I have plot where the x-axis starts from 0-100. I want to change it to 10-100. I would be grateful if someone could give any suggestion.

Comment: okay sorry got it `plt.xlim(xmax = 100, xmin = 10)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib  - similar for x axis.

Comment: Please do not downvote the question. I know the question is silly but still, it has answers submitted. Deleting this question will affect the future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use `pyplot` for a simple plot, you can try [this function](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.xlim(10, 100)
```

If you want to set specific `axes`, you can try [this method](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xlim):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(10, 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

From a SO community wiki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734587/why-is-set-xlim-not-setting-the-x-limits-in-my-figure)

> set_xlim() limits the data that is displayed on the plot.
>
> In order to change the bounds of the axis, use set_xbound()

So I'm pretty sure you actually want

```
ax.set_xbound(lower=10, upper=100)
```